# Отправить E-Mail с разных SMTP аккаунтов

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, email, sendmail

Имеется `UsersMailer < ActionMailer::Base`, в нём два экшена:

```
def confirmation_email(user)
  load_settings('confirm')
  @user = user
  @key = user.confirmation_key
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => 'E-Mail Confirmation')
end

def password_instructions(user)
  load_settings('forget')
  @user = user
  @key = @user.password_key
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => 'Reset password')
end
```

И метод:

```
def load_settings(task)
  options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'email-conf.yml'))[Rails.env][task]
  logger.debug options['address’]    #Эта штука выводит верный адрес, поэтому, проблема не в чтении из YAML
  UsersMailer.smtp_settings = {      #Проблема тут
      :address => options['address'],
      :port => options['port'],
      :domain => options['domain'],
      :authentication => options['authentication'],
      :user_name => options['user_name'],
      :password => options['password']
  }
end
```

задача которого - загружать настройки из `YAML`. Но есть проблема: `UsersMailer.smtp_settings` не устанавливает настройки, и e-mail’ы, судя по логу:

> Sent mail to niki-timofe@ya.ru (8ms)
> Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 16:32:43 +0400
> To: niki-timofe@ya.ru Message-ID:
> [514afdeb43872_2ad3ff4eabdb47836677@nikita-mac.mail](mailto:514afdeb43872_2ad3ff4eabdb47836677@nikita-mac.mail)
> Subject: Reset
> password Mime-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: text/plain; 
> charset=UTF-8
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

уходят через `sendmail`. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо самого Mailer’a следует использовать `ActionMailer::Base`

```
def load_settings(task)
  options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'email-conf.yml'))[Rails.env][task]
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address => options['address'],
      :port => options['port'],
      :domain => options['domain'],
      :authentication => options['authentication'],
      :user_name => options['user_name'],
      :password => options['password']
  }
end
```

и нужно не забыть добавить `:from => ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:user_name]`

```
def confirmation_email(user)
  load_settings('confirm')
  @user = user
  @key = user.confirmation_key
  mail(:to => user.email, :from => ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:user_name], :subject => 'E-Mail Confirmation')
end

def password_instructions(user)
  load_settings('forget')
  @user = user
  @key = @user.password_key
  mail(:to => user.email, :from => ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:user_name], :subject => 'Reset password')
end
```

#### UPD:

По логам невозможно понять как отправляется `e-mail`, разве что, только по времени отправки запроса.